# Is it possible to use MIPS register names with GAS (GNU assembler)?

Tags: assembly, gnu, mips, binutils

If I use register names I get:

```
Error: illegal operands `add $t0,$zero,$zero'
```

If I use register number (`$8` instead of `$t0` and `$0` instead of `$zero`) it works.
(I'm using binutils 2.17).

Comment: Binutils 2.18 and later do support symbolic register names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GNU assembler doesn't support symbolic register names directly.  A common approach, if using gcc to drive the assembler, is to use the ".S" extension for the assembler source file (which tells gcc to pass the source through the C preprocessor before the assembler) and #include a header file containing definitions like:

```
#define zero $0
#define v0   $2
#define v1   $3
```

Then the assembler source can have statements like

```
add v0, zero, zero
```

Comment: Minor quibble: `v0` and `v1` are `$2` and `$3` (`$1` is `at`)!

Comment: You're right - that's what I get for trusting my memory, will correct.

Comment: Note that the header might already be part of your system. Look for a file such as `/usr/include/sys/reg.h` or `/usr/include/mips-linux-gnu/sys/regdef.h`.