# Beginner Errors On When Compiling a MIPS Assembly Source

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to learn MIPS Assembly by learning [MIPS Assembly Language Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131420445). In the book I have this code(**extracted from the page 37 of the book**):

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "\n Please Input a Value: "
bye: .asciiz "\n Bye!"
.globl main
.text

main:
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, prompt
   syscall

   li $v0, 5
   syscall
   beqz $v0, end
   move $a0, $v0
   li $v0, 1
   syscall
   b main


end:
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, bye
   syscall

   li $v0, 10
   syscall
```

I have a [cross-compiled binutils](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~nakazato/tips/xgcc.html) targeted to `mips-elf`, but when I've tried  to Assemble the code, I got some errors

> ubuntu@eeepc:~/Desktop$ mips-elf-as test-mips.asm
>   test-mips.asm: Assembler messages:
>   test-mips.asm:8: Error: illegal operands 'li'
>   test-mips.asm:9: Error: illegal operands 'la'
>   test-mips.asm:12: Error: illegal operands 'li'
>   test-mips.asm:14: Error: illegal operands 'beqz'
>   test-mips.asm:15: Error: illegal operands 'move'
>   test-mips.asm:16: Error: illegal operands 'li'
>   test-mips.asm:22: Error: illegal operands 'li'
>   test-mips.asm:23: Error: illegal operands 'la'
>   test-mips.asm:26: Error: illegal operands 'li'
>   ubuntu@eeepc:~/Desktop$

**I'm using x86 Ubuntu Hardy Herron to cross-compile to MIPS**

What is wrong?

Comment: could you see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403667/mips-hex-output/9403758#comment11954218_9403758 and provide a response as to what the process is for turning a .s assembly file as you have above to an object file? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using an older version of binutils which does not support the symbolic names for MIPS registers.

binutils 2.17 (as referenced in the cross-compilation instructions you linked to) does not understand `$v0`, `$a0` etc. (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721192/is-it-possible-to-use-mips-register-names-with-gas-gnu-assembler)).

However, if you are building the tools yourself anyway, a good solution would be to move to a later version of binutils: versions from 2.18 onwards *do* support symbolic register names.  Your example assembles correctly with either 2.18 or the latest version, 2.20.

Comment: Good catch! All the instructions that are failing have the $v0/$a0-type operands (except the first 'la' which is a bit strange) and the errors specify operands, despite showing the _opcodes_ (which is what threw me off). +1.

Comment: Turns out the first `la` probably _did_ have the error. It was misspelled `ls` in the original question and the error output wasn't updated properly when that was changed (`ls` error was deleted but `la` error wasn't put in, I'd guess). I've modified the question to insert the actual error output for that changed line as well (so the question makes more sense).

Answer (score 4):

Well, the `li` and `la` instructions are pseudo instructions which *should* be recognised by the assembler but it's possible your environment needs to do something to define them (it wouldn't surprise me if they were macros).

Try changing them to their "real" form:

```
li $v0,4   -->   lui $v0,0;       ori $v0,$v0,4
la $a0,bye -->   lui $a0,bye>>16; ori $a0,$a0,bye&ffff
```

Or whatever your particular MIPS assembler uses for `RIGHT-SHIFT-16-BITS` and `AND`.

The `ls` instruction I've never seen before. Are you sure that's not a typo for `la`? And I think `beqz` should be `beq`. Most CPUs would use the same instruction in different ways, an example being that both decrementing a register down to zero (z) *and* comparing a register with something (eq) would set the zero flag.

None of `ls`, `beqz` or `move` show up in the [MIPS assembler Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture) although the latter two are listed as pseudo-instructions in [Patterson & Hennessy](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/HP_AppA.pdf).

So it's looking more and more like there's some extra set-up you need to do to get the pseudo-instructions working.

Comment: Sorry about the `ls`, it was just my mistake.

Comment: If I try to change, I just got more `illegal operands` error, but now with `lui` and `ori`.

Comment: Take a look on the page of that book, the code is like that. Now I've copied and pasted.

Comment: Sorry, @Nathan, that's about the extent of my help. If it's complaining about the lui, it's not a pseudo-instruction problem. Basically, the only instructions working there are syscall and b. I'd be tempted to think it was an assembler for a different CPU is that weren't the case.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. I'm going to wait for someone that can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is your sequence of listing of li and la, unless you load an address, you can't load immediate and tell $v0 to hold on to the string you want to appear.. try putting the la first before li in each case... well as for pseudo instructions, yes, that can be the problem as well, but my suggestion is worth a try.