# unknow register name, asm

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I want to compile assemble code (MIPS) by using C, while I came across the problem about "no register name". The error information is:

```
ABS.c:8:2: error: unknown register name ‘$s1’ in ‘asm’
```

and my code (ABS.c) are as follow:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int ABS(int x)
{
int x_abs;

__asm__ __volatile__(
    "move $s1, %1\n"
    "bgez $s1, DONE\n"
    "NOP\n"
    "mult $s1, #-1\n"
    "mflo $s1\n"
    "DONE: move %0, $s1\n"
    : "=r"(x_abs)
    : "r"(x)
    : "$s1");
return x_abs;       
}

int main()
{
int result = ABS(2);
printf("%d", result);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I wonder how I could fix that problem, THX！

Comment: Are you *sure* you're compiling for MIPS?  Run `gcc -v`.  If you see x86-64 or i386, you're using a compiler that targets your x86 desktop.  Your code compiles fine on MIPS gcc5.4 on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/g/LQ9t35.  And gives the same error you describe with x86 gcc.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have an old version of gcc/binutils: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721192/is-it-possible-to-use-mips-register-names-with-gas-gnu-assembler

Comment: @Matteo: The OP's error message is from the compiler trying to process the clobber list; it hasn't made it to the assembler yet.  The dup you linked will be a problem later, but gcc5.4 *does* understand `$s1`.  Ah, I see you un-duped it :)

Comment: @PeterCordes: eh the problem with the dupe-hammer is that it's too direct; I merely wanted to suggest it, and thought I had no gold badge in [assembly] - but this is [C]! About the clobber list: that does explain the strange error message, indeed I expected the assembler to balk immediately on `move` if it was being processed by x86 as.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Ah I see.  For me it's sometimes the other way around; I mostly follow tags that tend to also have asm and/or x86 tags, so it's an unpleasant surprise when it turns out the OP only tagged x86-64 or whatever, and not assembly or C or C++, or something like that.  At least once I've asked someone else to edit the tag list before I spend my close vote, when I notice ahead of time :P

Answer (score 0):

All registers in MIPS are accessible through [symbolic names or numbers](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch05s03.html). I had the same issue, I solved it by using numbers instead of symbolic names, e.g. `mov $17, %1` instead of `mov $s1, %1`